# HttpservletRequest and response in Spring JMS listener

Tags: spring, spring-jms

Can someone tell whether is there a way to get HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse in Spring JMS listener class? My JMS listener is defined in springContext.xml file.

Comment: The JMS listener gets triggered when JMS messages are available. Why would you have an HTTPRequest in the same context?

Comment: I need to invoke some method which has HttpServletRequest/Response object as params.. Is there a way to mock these objects

Comment: Eh, what method? If it's one you wrote, and it doesn't NEED the HttpRequest (since I don't see a situation where you would *always* have both that and a JMS message), then just pass null? Or refactor...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `JAXDispatcher` to invoke my service, from my JMS listener.

```
jaxbDispatcher.doGET(null, url, null, "application/xml", true);
```

Comment: You should accept this answer if you solved your own problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't have access to HTTP servlet request and response within JMS listeners. These are completely independent modules that can even reside on different physical servers.

You *can* use [`MockHttpServletRequest`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) and [`MockHttpServletResponse`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletResponse.html) from `spring-test.jar` - but they are meant to be used within unit/integration tests, not in production code.

I would really like to see your code that requires `MockHttpServletRequest` and response. My guess is that it can be refactored or redesigned to use only relevant fields from the above, like request URL or user name.

Comment: Informative expansion of my comments. Didn't know about those mock objects, but there is a bigger problem/confusion going on here. My money goes on a refactor/redesign solution. +1